# Mock products and setting values on unit testing

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit

I've created an API extension that manages gallery easily for our demands and now I wanted to create a unit testing.

For example, one functionality is: give an 'sku' and 'entry' object (with base64 img) and API adds this image on that product.

This is the class I want to test:

```
<?php

namespace Gsp\ApiExtension\Model;

use Gsp\ApiExtension\Api\SGIMediaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ImageContentValidatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class SGIMedia implements SGIMediaInterface {

    /**
     * @var StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository
     */
    protected $storeRepository;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var ImageContentValidatorInterface
     */
    protected $contentValidator;

    /**
     * @var ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface
     */
    protected $galleryManagement;

    /**
     * @param StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository
     * @param ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface $galleryManagement
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param ImageContentValidatorInterface $contentValidator
     */
    public function __construct(StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository, ProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementInterface $galleryManagement, ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository, ImageContentValidatorInterface $contentValidator) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->contentValidator = $contentValidator;
        $this->galleryManagement = $galleryManagement;
        $this->storeRepository = $storeRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function update($skus, ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface $entry) {
        $sku_array = explode('|', $skus);

        foreach ($sku_array as $sku) {
            $this->galleryManagement->create($sku, $entry);
        }
    }

(...)

}
```

1) I need to mock a product, I've already did that, but then all attributes are NULL, so I would need to set an SKU at least. setData is not working. I'm stuck here.

I did this:

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
*/
protected $product;

protected function setUp() {
    $this->product = $this->createMock(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class, [], [], '', false);

    $this->product->setSku('test');
    var_dump($this->product->getSku()); //returns NULL

    $this->product->setData('sku', 'test');
    var_dump($this->product->getData('sku')); //returns NULL

    $this->product->save();
    var_dump($this->product->getData('sku')); //returns NULL
 }
```

2) Then I get my model and call my method passing this SKU and a fixed entry as a parameters.

3) Verify the product has this entry.

By the way, I'm very new at unit testing and on Magento too.

Comment: can you also post the method you are trying to test? maybe the full class you are testing?

Comment: I added my class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$product->method('getSku')->willReturn('test');`
Mocks can be configured in many ways! It is worth reading the documentation here: 
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Comment: But doing this will not help at the next step, I think. I want to call the function `update` passing an sku as parameter. I need that sku is associated at this product

Comment: I think you really want to write an integration test using real objects instead of a unit test.

Comment: Well I don't know, all I need is a product that could do this functionality about adding an entry object inside it and verify that entry is correct. Can't do that a mock object?

Comment: if you need "real" product functionality, you really might need an integration test. You might want to have a look at how to create fixtures in m2. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_entities/mtf_fixture.html It allows you to create a product object just for your test and then test against it's functionalities

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will be less complicated if we could separate the required logic to test in different methods and test that specific method using the PHPUnit framework when doing the TDD development.

For example, in your method `update()`, I can see two sections.

Section 1:

```
$sku_array = explode('|', $skus);
```

Section 2:

```
foreach ($sku_array as $sku) {
   $this->galleryManagement->create($sku, $entry);
}
```

So if you would need to add a unit test for section one, you can create a separate method called `getExplodedSkus()` for that section and use `assertEquals()` method (compare exploded array values) in PHPUnit. For section two, you can create another method called `createGalleryItem()` and use `assertInstanceOf()` method (verify `$sku_array` has product type objects) in PHPUnit.

FYI: PHP variable names have to be camelCase and not the snake_case. `$sku_array` should be `$skuArray`.

Hope this will help to make it less complex.

Cheers!